# Calling a Control on a subform

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, controls, subform

I'm looking for a way to access a control on a subform, currently everything I have tried gives me an error of "cannot find".

> my main form "frm_View" contains the subform "subform_View2"
>
> subform_View2 contains a tab container
>
> the tab container contains yet another subform "subform_View3" on the
>   first tab
>
> Separate form "frmAnswers"

I need to access a control on subform_View3 in order to insert information obtained from frmAnswers.

I've tried:

```
me.subform_view3!frm_View!control1
me.subform_view3!subform_view2!subform_View3!control1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you must treat the tab control as a special kind of container, with each page behaving similarly to another subform.

I have created an example, see picture below.
[image]

The main form contains a TabControl (named tabControl) and the first page contains a subform (called SubForm) and that contains a text box (txb).

To get to the value of the text box you will need to path through the tab control like this:

```
Me.tabControl.Pages(0).Controls("SubForm")!txb.Value
```

or

```
Me.tabControl.Pages("Page1").Controls("SubForm")!txb.Value
```

or

```
Me.tabControl.Pages("Page1").Controls("SubForm").Controls("txb").Value
```

Notice that the SubForm is part of the "Controls" collection of the page, so you'll need to identify the tab control first, then the page (either by name or zero-based index) and then the subform itself to get to it's controls.

**EDIT**

If you want to call it from a form-independent code, you can target the form like this

```
Forms!MainForm!tabControl.Pages("Page1").Controls("SubForm")!txb.Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The action is being called from a completely different form so I believe the "Me" distinction won't work.

Comment: That doesn't matter, it can be replaced by parent form, the tab control handling is what is important.

Comment: Edited my answer to replicate your problem on my example more closely.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked great